# Why do I keep getting the error "File "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable"?

Tags: python, typeerror

Hope someone can help explain why I keep getting the following error in Python.

Python version: Python 3.10.4
OS: Windows 11 in a vm

Steps to reproduce the error in REPL or JuyterLab.

```
def minmax(items):
    return min(items), max(items)
lst = [98, 34, 78, 1, 0, -10, -19, -1]
(min, max) = minmax(lst) # **no error**
min, max = minmax(lst) # **error**. after this point I cannot call minmax without an error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in minmax
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
'int' object is not callable

(min, max) = minmax(lst) # **error**
a, b = minmax(lst) # **error**
min, max = minmax(lst) # **error**
```

restart REPL or restart the kernel in JypterLab will solve the problem. This kind of gives me a hint that the issue might have something to do with the Python binds the variable with an Object.

**Request**: Whoever takes the time to respond, please also include your thought process. For example, "I have seen this before and before of my experience I know ..." or "I read the Python doc and saw ... which led me to experiment and discover..."

I want to be able to debug these myself and want to understand the thougt process that was used to get to the answer.

**What have I tried so far?**
-REPL to experiment
-Jyputer notebook to experiment
-read https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-typeerror-int-object-is-not-callable/

Comment: `# **error**`—what is the _complete, specific_ error? Please read [ask].

Comment: Hint: the first time that you call `minmax`, what are the names of the **global variables** that you assign to? The second time that you call `minmax`, what are the names of the functions it tries to look up and call, again as **global variables** (since that's what all built-in functions are)?

Comment: "Whoever takes the time to respond, please also include your thought process." Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. There are standard steps that you should take in order to track down problems in any code, in any programming language.

Comment: "read https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-typeerror-int-object-is-not-callable/" What happens in your code is exactly what is called "scenario #1" on that web site.

Comment: As a heads-up, these kinds of mistakes never really go away completely - you just get faster at catching them, until it's so fast that you catch yourself in the middle of typing.

Comment: Hi Chris,
The complete error is in the question. Regardless, decorator-factory was able to help and provide help.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in minmax
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
'int' object is not callable

Comment: Hi Karl Knechtel,
Thank you for taking the time to reply. decorator-factory was able to help. I'll review the links and really appreciate the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```py
(min, max) = minmax(lst)
```

you're assigning integers to `min` and `max`. Then, you try to call these integers here:

```py
def minmax(items):
    return min(items), max(items)  # this line
```

Try this in your interactive console:

```py
>>> min([1, 0, 2])
0
>>> min = 42
>>> min([1, 0, 2])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
>>>
```

> Request: Whoever takes the time to respond, please also include your thought process.

Whenever you see a traceback:

1. Find the line it refers to
2. Try to find all things that could trigger it.

So:

1. The traceback is pointing to this line:

```
    return min(items), max(items)
```

2. The traceback says: `'int' object is not callable`. This means that you're trying to call an `int` object. You're only calling `min` and `max` on this line, so it must be that `min` or `max` are integers. How could it be?
3. You might notice that later, you assign to `min` and `max` in your code.

Comment: what a n00b mistake. Thanks a lot!. I am going to experiment a little bit and then mark the answer as "answered" and upvote the answer.